# How to Get all Size Variants using Amazon's Product Advertising API

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

Right now, the XML response that I get from the API contains just the size of the clothing corresponding to its ASIN. For the case of ASIN `B0069NZPHA`, the `Size` is `Small`. However if you were to visit its [detail page url](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0069NZPHA), you can see that there are 2 sizes, Small and Medium.

Is it possible get all the sizes related to a particular ASIN?

**XML Response**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ASIN] => B0069NZPHA
    [ParentASIN] => B0069O8WN8
    [DetailPageURL] => http://www.amazon.com/2b-Haley-Beaded-Top-TANGERINE/dp/B0069NZPHA%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAJG3VKWBENQUGEYZA%26tag%3Dyoozu-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3DB0069NZPHA

    ...

    [ItemAttributes] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Binding] => Apparel
        [Brand] => 2b by bebe
        [CatalogNumberList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [CatalogNumberListElement] => 192612
            )

        [Color] => Tangerine
        [Department] => womens
        [Feature] => Array
            (
                [0] => SKU 192612
                [1] => Style 60HZK201N240
            )

        [Label] => bebe
        [Manufacturer] => bebe
        [PackageDimensions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [Height] => 230
                [Length] => 1120
                [Weight] => 35
                [Width] => 670
            )

        [ProductGroup] => Apparel
        [ProductTypeName] => SHIRT
        [Publisher] => bebe
        [Size] => Small
        [Studio] => bebe
        [Title] => 2b Haley Beaded Top - TANGERINE (S)
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check [ItemLookup](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) and especially the **ResponseGroup** = [Variations](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Variations.html) / [VariationsSummary](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_VariationSummary.html). (Or try any other ResponseGroup, maybe some group will show all the sizes)

Comment: It's returning just one color and one size.

Answer (score 1):

I used Variations response group (ItemLookup) with ParentASIN to get all of sizes and colors

Comment: Hi @Sallee please explain how to get all sizes and colors in particular product